# clear data from shared pref in android app

Tags: android

As i am new to android development.

After user clicks on sign out button from my app i want to delete all the info which i have stored in shared pref.

i used this `editor.clear()` but it won't work,

I want to delete that XML file which is created by shared pref after user clicks on log out button i want to delete that file at run time?

thnx for any help....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to commit your changes:

```
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Hoper this help

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code by editing your original question. We haven't a magic ball :D

Comment: editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.clear();      //editor.remove(TwitterSession.TWEET_AUTH_KEY); //editor.remove(TwitterSession.TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY);
//mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
// accessToken=null;
editor.commit(); 
TestPost.this.finish();                                              All the above code is under on clicklistener of logout button

Answer (score 4):

Try `editor.clear();` followed by a `editor.commit();`

---

*Edit:*

Here is one example that I've used:

```
Preference clearPref = (Preference) findPreference("clearAll");
    clearPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        SharedPreferences settings =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());                          
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();                
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "All data cleared!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

});
```

Comment: As Francesco said, please post that specific part of your code

Comment: editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.clear();   // editor.remove(TwitterSession.TWEET_AUTH_KEY);
// editor.remove(TwitterSession.TWEET_AUTH_SECRET_KEY);
mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
accessToken=null;
editor.commit(); 
TestPost.this.finish();

Comment: How is editor and sharedPref initialized? And what part exactly isn't working?

Comment: sharedPref    = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editor    =sharedPref.edit();                                                  the code which is written in logout button is not working i.e. i want to delete that xml which sharedpref will create in it.

Comment: The xml file that is created on internal storage won't be deleted. `clear()` only deletes it's content.

Comment: Hmm, can you check if `editor.commit()` returns true? Maybe something is wrong with your context